# Extract first part of path in NextJS rewrites

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is there a way to use the rewrites feature to extract the first part of the path?
I need to rewrite http://localhost/customerA/pageA to http://localhost/pageA?customer=customerA

So far I tried to configure the rewrites like this:

```
async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: `/:customer/:path*`,
          destination: `/:path*?customer=:customer`,
        },
      ],
    };
```

But aparently it goes onto an infinite loop

Comment: Maybe `/:foo/:bar(.+)` to `/:bar?customer=:foo`. Not tested though, something like that should work.

Comment: Try removing the `*`, i.e. ``source: `/:customer/:path`,`` then ``destination: `/:path?customer=:customer`,``.